# Xpath expression help - multiple expressions

Tags: xpath, expression, element, xmlnode

Given the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Patients>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="996-756-495" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
    <id extension="775-756-495" root="2.16.840.1.113883.14.6"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>Henry</given>
        <family>Levin</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19320924"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
      <name>Good Health Clinic</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="2012030111:32"/>
  </patientRole>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="65" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.933"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>Paul</given>
        <family>Pappel</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19551217"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id extension="84756-11241-283-OPTD-3322" root="1.2.3.4.5.6.1.8.9.0"/>
      <name> Dr.med. Hans Topp-Glucklich</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="201201152200"/>
  </patientRole>
  <patientRole>
    <id extension="800001" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
    <patient>
      <name>
        <given>JEANNE</given>
        <family>PETIT</family>
      </name>
      <administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
      <birthTime value="19480105"/>
    </patient>
    <providerOrganization>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
      <name>Good Health Clinic</name>
    </providerOrganization>
    <admissionTime value="20120101T22:00"/>
  </patientRole>
</Patients>
```

I need to find out a xpath expression for each to do the following.

I am new to XML/Xpath and have tried quite a few expressions but i cant quite get what I need.

1. Patient element nodes of the patients that have two ids
2. Number of patients admitted to "Good Health Clinic" in January 2012:

With this one I tried `/Patients/patientRole[providerOrganization/name='Good Health Clinic' and substring(admissionTime/@value,1,6)='201201']` which will generate it but the website i am working off of will not take that submission so i am wondering if there is another expression that will generate that perhaps a less complex one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i cant quite get what I need.
>
> 1. Patient element nodes of the patients that have two ids

**Use**:

```
/*/*[id[2]]/patient
```

.
.
.

> 1. Number of patients admitted to "Good Health Clinic" in January 2012:

**Use**:

```
count(/*/*[starts-with(admissionTime/@value, '201201')]/patient)
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*[id[2]]/patient"/>
  =====
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "count(/*/*[starts-with(admissionTime/@value, '201201')]/patient)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Patients>
    <patientRole>
        <id extension="996-756-495" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
        <id extension="775-756-495" root="2.16.840.1.113883.14.6"/>
        <patient>
            <name>
                <given>Henry</given>
                <family>Levin</family>
            </name>
            <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
            <birthTime value="19320924"/>
        </patient>
        <providerOrganization>
            <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
            <name>Good Health Clinic</name>
        </providerOrganization>
        <admissionTime value="2012030111:32"/>
    </patientRole>
    <patientRole>
        <id extension="65" root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.933"/>
        <patient>
            <name>
                <given>Paul</given>
                <family>Pappel</family>
            </name>
            <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
            <birthTime value="19551217"/>
        </patient>
        <providerOrganization>
            <id extension="84756-11241-283-OPTD-3322" root="1.2.3.4.5.6.1.8.9.0"/>
            <name> Dr.med. Hans Topp-Glucklich</name>
        </providerOrganization>
        <admissionTime value="201201152200"/>
    </patientRole>
    <patientRole>
        <id extension="800001" root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
        <patient>
            <name>
                <given>JEANNE</given>
                <family>PETIT</family>
            </name>
            <administrativeGenderCode code="F" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>
            <birthTime value="19480105"/>
        </patient>
        <providerOrganization>
            <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5"/>
            <name>Good Health Clinic</name>
        </providerOrganization>
        <admissionTime value="20120101T22:00"/>
    </patientRole>
</Patients>
```

**the Xpath expressions are evaluated and the results of this evaluation are copied to the output:**

```
<patient>

   <name>

      <given>Henry</given>

      <family>Levin</family>

   </name>

   <administrativeGenderCode code="M" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1"/>

   <birthTime value="19320924"/>

</patient>
  =====
  2
```